# Print image after it's been generated [c#]

Tags: c#, image, file, printing

I have the following method that loads in a blank template image, draws the relevant information on it and saves it to another file. I want to change this slightly to achieve the following:

- load in the template image
- draw the relevant information on it
- print it

I don't want to save it, just print it out. Here's my existing method:

```
public static void GenerateCard(string recipient, string nominee, string reason, out string filename)
    {
        // Get a bitmap.
        Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap("template.jpg");

        Graphics graphicImage;

        // Wrapped in a using statement to automatically take care of IDisposable and cleanup
        using (graphicImage = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
        {
            ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID
            // for the Quality parameter category.
            Encoder myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;

            graphicImage.DrawString(recipient, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(480, 33));
            graphicImage.DrawString(WordWrap(reason, 35), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(566, 53));
            graphicImage.DrawString(nominee, new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(492, 405));
            graphicImage.DrawString(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular), SystemBrushes.WindowText, new Point(490, 425));
            EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
            EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

            filename = recipient + " - " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().Replace("/", "-") + ".jpg";

            bmp1.Save(filename, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        }
    }
```

Hope you can help,
Brett

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just print it to the printer without saving

This is the most simple example I could come up with.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(100, 100);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
{
    g.DrawString("Hello", this.Font, Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 0));
}

PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += (object printSender, PrintPageEventArgs printE) =>
    {
        printE.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(b, new Point(0, 0));
    };

PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
dialog.ShowDialog();
pd.PrinterSettings = dialog.PrinterSettings;
pd.Print();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you use the PrintDocument class, you can print without needing to save the image.

```
var pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;

pd.Print()
```

And in the pd_PrintPage eventhandler:

```
void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics gr = e.Graphics;

    //now you can draw on the gr object you received using some of the code you posted.
}
```

NOTE: Don't dispose the Graphics object you received in the eventhandler. This is done by the PrintDocument object itself...

Answer (score 2):

Use the [PrintPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) event;

```
   private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e) {
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    }
```